# Is it possible to install broadcast receiver into internal memory?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I've Android appliaction which need to recive `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. However it is desirable to install my application into external storage. I know that only applications installed into internal storage can recieve this broadcast, so I wonder is there any way to install broadcast reciver separetly from app into internal storage?

I've tried to achieve this with following manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">

    <receiver android:name="com.example.BootCompletedReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
              android:installLocation="internalOnly">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   ...............

</application>
 </manifest>
```

But this doesn't seems to work. Any ideas? 
Or maybe I can handle this broadcast in some other way?

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> ?

Comment: yes, I've tried to add this permission to whole application, but it also doesn't help, so in last version I decided to add it only for my receiver